# GitLab on a Windows 10

Tags: gitlab

I would like to make Gitlab available for my students. We have been assigned a PC with a Windows 10 installation by the admin.

Is there a way to install GitLab on a Windows 10 machine without using Docker or a virtual machine?

Comment: GitLab requires a debian-based Linux operating system, so the answer here is probably "no". You would need docker or a VM -- maybe WSL will work, but IIRC that requires docker.

Answer (score 0):

WIndows 10 default have Ubuntu Linux onboard, but it's not default turned on. If You'll turn on Linux subsystem on windows you may try to setup gitlab on it. Gitlab isn't require GUI and i think it probably will be OK. [This video](https://youtu.be/Cvrqmq9A3tA) helps You to turn Linux subsystem on. But you'll need to each time your PC power up log in and start gitlab services manually, because systemctl in Linux subsystem was "truncated". Other way to make an sheduller job on event "power up" to run **startservise.sh** file with content like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudoPW="YourPasswordInLinuxSubsystemYouCreatedDuringActivateIt"
echo $sudoPW | sudo -S --prompt="" service <gitlab service> start
unset sudoPW
```